# How to serialize an function?

Tags: ios, serialization, interpreter

There is a way to serialize/deserialize a function inside an obj-c application?

I the near future i need to change the function's implementation without update my executable.

I know there isn't a way to serialize a function pointer / nsoperation / block so i'm looking for an alternative way...maybe can i include a python interpreter inside my app and download a script from websever?

Comment: For what purpose? You could possibly serialize an object & a selector, but that's about all I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the SDK licence agreement, you're not permitted to download any code whatsoever — it's a thin-end-of-the-wedge issue versus Apple's desire to vet all applications.

In technical terms, you'd need to include Python or LUA or something like that. JavaScript is included but accessible only through a very awkward process of interaction with web views.

Comment: apple policies aren't a problem for now. Javascript is a very good idea! I know how evaluate javascript with a webview. Python or LUA interpreter are to complicated to configure for me.